# check if list contains atom key and has a value

Tags: elixir

How do I check if a key value pair exists in a List?

```
options = [symbol: ?|]

args = options[:symbol]

if args[:symbol] and not is_integer(args[:symbol]) do
...
```

This gives me the error
`(BadBooleanError) expected a boolean on left-side of "and", got: 124`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between [`and/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#and/2) and [`&&/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#&&/2) (the same applies to [`or/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#or/2) and [`||/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#%7C%7C/2).) The former operates on *boolean* values, the latter on `truthy` and `falsey`.

So one might change the code to

```elixir
if args[:symbol] && not is_integer(args[:symbol]), do: ...
```

But this code is still not correct (at least it smells.) Keywords might have `nil`s as values, so one must clearly distinguish between *has `nil` value* and *does not have a value*.

For that we have [`Keyword.has_key?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#has_key?/2). That said, the correct code would be:

```elixir
if Keyword.has_key?(args, :symbol) and not is_integer(args[:symbol]), do: ...
```

Note `and/2` here; it’s now correct because `Keyword.has_key/2` does indeed return a boolean.